# format time period with jq console tool

Tags: time, jq

I have time in milliseconds and I want to format it to time period. For example like this(not necessary exactly like this): 1d 23h 15m 13s.
How can it be done with jq?

Comment: You'll need to do it yourself -- write your own math+branching logic, just as you would in any other language. Have you made any effort to do so? Could you show your attempted work?

Comment: jq170727 answer is better that I could ever invent. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution which does the calculations directly.

```
 def roundto(n):   (./n|floor)*n ;
 def timefmt(ms):
   def calcsecs:                             .s_to_m = (.seconds | roundto(60)) | .secs = .seconds - .s_to_m ;
   def calcmins:     .minutes = .s_to_m/60 | .m_to_h = (.minutes | roundto(60)) | .mins = .minutes - .m_to_h ;
   def calchrs:      .hours   = .m_to_h/60 | .h_to_d = (.hours   | roundto(24)) | .hrs  = .hours   - .h_to_d ;
   def calcdays:     .days    = .h_to_d/24 ;
   def fmtelt(e;u):  if e>0 then " \(e)\(u)" else "" end ;
   def fmt:
       .s = " \(.secs)s"
     | .m = fmtelt(.mins; "m")
     | .h = fmtelt(.hrs; "h")
     | .d = fmtelt(.days; "d")
     | "\(.d)\(.h)\(.m)\(.s)"[1:]
   ;
   {seconds: (ms/1000)|floor} | calcsecs | calcmins | calchrs | calcdays | fmt
;     
timefmt($ms)
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` then

```
$ jq -Mnr --argjson ms 1505752580000 -f filter.jq
```

outputs

```
17427d 16h 36m 20s
```

for smaller intervals only the relevent fields are shown. e.g.

```
$ jq -Mnr --argjson ms 1505750 -f filter.jq
```

outputs

```
25m 5s
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise but straightforward implementation of a function for converting milliseconds to a condensed "d h m s" string, with no rounding. It would be trivial to modify this to include the millisecond remainder as well.

```
# input: milliseconds
# output: ignore millisecond remainder
def formattime:
  def f(u): if .>0 then " \(.)" + u else "" end ;
  # emit a stream of the remainders
  def s: foreach (1000,60,60,24,1) as $i ([.,0];
    .[0] as $n
    | ($n/$i | floor) as $m
    | [$m, $n - ($m*$i)];
    if $i == 1 then .[0] else .[1] end);

 [s] as [$ms, $s, $m, $h, $d]
  | {s : " \($s)s",
     m : ($m|f("m")),
     h : ($h|f("h")),
     d : ($d|f("d")) }
  | "\(.d)\(.h)\(.m)\(.s)"[1:]
;
formattime
```

**Example:**

```
$ jq -r -f formattime.jq
1505752580000 
17427d 16h 36m 20s
6006
6s
1
0s
```